# Сортировка вставками, посчитать сравнения и перестановки

Tags: php, сортировка

Вот участок кода с сортировкой:

```
//Сортировка вставками
  for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr2); $i++) {
    $x = $arr2[$i];
    for ($j = $i - 1; $j >= 0 && $arr2[$j] > $x; $j--) {
      /* сдвигаем элементы вправо, пока выполняется условие
         $a[$j] > $a[$i] */
      $arr2[$j + 1] = $arr2[$j];
    }
    // на оставшееся после сдвига место, ставим $a[$i]
    $arr2[$j + 1] = $x;
  }
```

Что и куда нужно добавить, что бы посчитать количество сравнений и перестановок?

Comment: ну как минимум переменые нормально обозвать

Comment: @Naumov а дальше?

Comment: ввести переменную которая будет содержать подщитаную сумму. О каких сравнениях речь?

Comment: Это алгоритм сортировки вставками, он сравнивает элементы (целые числа), и сдвигает их, если они расположены не по возрастанию. Вот количество этих сравнений и сдвигов надо посчитать.

Comment: вы попробуйте вообще разобраться как работает алгоритм, тогда может и ответ станет очевидным?

Comment: Пробовал, поэтому и задал тут вопрос

Comment: Для начала программу почистить надо. Индекс $i изменять от нуля, j - от $i. Тогда не будет стоять вопрос, считать условие $j>=0 сравнением или ценой программной реализации.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov так вопрос все равно останется открытым, что и куда нужно добавить, что бы посчитать количество сравнений и перестановок?

Answer (score 0):

Классический алгоритм сортировки вставками предполагает три основные операции на каждый элемент:

1. Двоичный поиск места вставки.
2. Перестановку группы элементов на соседние места.
3. Вставку нового элемента на своё место.

Операции по п.1 - это "чистые" сравнения. Операции п.2 - это сдвиг области памяти, который допускает разные варианты реализации в зависимости от формата исходных данных (для битовых полей - одни, для 1-байтовых данных - другие, для объектов сравниваемые и перемещаемые данные вообще лежат в разных местах...).

В рассматриваемой программе форматы сравниваемых и исходных данных совпадают, что позволяет при отказе от бинарного поиска совместить сравнения и перестановки. Т.е.

1. Счётчик перестановок следует инкрементировать во внутреннем цикле.
2. Счётчик сравнений - во внешнем цикле.
3. По окончании циклов к показаниям счётчика сравнений следует добавлять показания счётчика перестановок, после чего умножить их на 2 (если есть сравнение j >= 0) или 1 (если его нет).
4. Следует указать, что формат исходных данных изначально требует по `n` дополнительных сравнений для `n-1` переставляемого элемента, за счёт чего бинарный поиск добавляет по две или по одной операции на элемент соответственно.